# Problema con mi consulta SQL INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT `idpago`, 
       clientes.nombres_cli, 
       `fecha_realizada`, `fechadesde`, 
       `fechahasta`, `cant_meses`, 
       `importe`, `total` 
FROM pagos AS pagado 
INNER JOIN clientes ON pagado.idcliente = clientes.idcliente 
WHERE clientes.idcliente = 3 
AND pagos.fecha_realizada = MAX(pagos.fecha_realizada)
```

Esta es mi consulta sql lo que quiero hacer es traer el ultimo registro del cliente con id 3 y me da error al colocar el "AND"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La primera imagen es la tabla cliente y la segunda es la tabla de pagos. Espero haber pasado bien los detalles de mi problema y cualquier ayuda me servirá mucho gracias.
Ah por cierto este es el error que me lanza

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pudieras tratar con una subconsulta, me suena a que el error es por que no existe un `FROM` que indique de donde proviene dicha columna.

Entonces en esta línea:

```
AND pagos.fecha_realizada = MAX(pagos.fecha_realizada)
```

Pudieras tratar de esta forma:

**Subconsulta**

```
AND pagos.fecha_realizada = (SELECT MAX(pagos.fecha_realizada) FROM pagos)
```

> Es decir estas buscando una igualdad que del lado izquierdo indica un valor a comparar a través de la columna fecha; como buscas el último registro por medio de la fecha mas reciente entonces colocamos la función de agregación por dentro de paréntesis del lado izquierdo para establecer la consulta que ha de devolvernos dicho valor.

Comment: Que tal amigo, probe asi mismo como dijiste y asi quedo al final mi codigo
`SELECT `idpago`, clientes.nombres_cli, `fecha_realizada`, `fechadesde`, `fechahasta`, `cant_meses`, `importe`, `total` FROM pagos INNER JOIN clientes ON pagos.idcliente = clientes.idcliente WHERE pagos.idcliente = 3 AND pagos.fecha_realizada = (SELECT MAX(pagos.fecha_realizada) FROM pagos)`
Y me funciono perfectamente, Muchas gracias!

Comment: @VictorAvila la consulta te sirvió? no me quedó claro tu comentario

Comment: Ahora corregí mi comentario, perdón jaja